# Value bellow was evaluated just now

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

In my angularjs application I added the jquery plugin jstree, so in my code I have this declared in a the link function of the directive responsible of adding the jstree :

```
scope.tree = $(element).jstree(scope.config);
```

I want after this done to do some jquery manupilation on the created DOM, like to select the first `li` :

```
console.log($(element).children("ul:first").children("li:first"));
```

But this returns an empty array, and chrome's console shows me a little `i` which says `Value bellow was evaluated just now`.

How can I solve this ?

Comment: wrap up your dom manipulation in `$timeout(function(){/*code here*/}, 0)`?

Comment: @kukkuz didnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by using the `$q` service from angularjs :

```
var promise = $q(function(resolve, reject){
                scope.tree = $(element).jstree(scope.config);
                resolve(scope.tree);
            });
            promise.then(function(data){
                $(data[0]).children("ul:first").children("li:first").append($compile(htmlElement)(scope));
            });
```